# kde install problem

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde

I've installed 16.0.4 version of Ubuntu.

But I don't like the default appearance of Ubuntu (Unity).

So after some searching I decided that I should install KDE.

I run this command in Terminal to install KDE:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

The installation process was ongoing, asked me a question to the effect that I can choose the default display.

"Sdaa" and "light" (or some things else)

and I choose "light".

Then the process was ongoing.

But I was confronted with an error in this file.

```
kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4% 3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And then I did some research for this problem and I run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -r account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then I run that code, and the installation is completed.

After I restarted the laptop to apply changes.

When loaded, the logo appeared Kubuntu.

But when the system booted, the previous appearance Unity appeared.

What should I do that I can I install KDE ?

Comment: For better results and less space used install Kubuntu directly: http://kubuntu.org/ . That said, all you need to do now is select the environment when booting by clicking the icon at the right of your username..

Comment: sorry ; I am a amateur and I do not know exactly.
What should I do after I download "Kubuntu 16.04 LTS"?